# Swagger usage with multiply parameters

Tags: go, swagger, swagger-2.0

Question how am I able to organize on Swagger two parameters with different type?
To be more specific, I want to gather from request the JSON information in view :

```
{
  "name": "ssm_parameter",
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

and also from form attached file to be uploaded.

I have tried to handle it on that way:

```
// api godoc
// @Summary API Index modulesUpload page
// @Tags apiModules
// @Produce json
// @Param json body apiModuleStruct true "modules upload"
// @Accept application/json
// @Param file formData file true "File to upload" format(multipart/form-data)
// @Accept multipart/form-data
// @Success 200 {object} string
// @Failure 400 {object} string
// @Router /api/upload [post]
// @Security ApiKeyAuth
```

Fields of params are correct on view, but still curl request is going on view (so json provided data is ignored):

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://127.0.0.1/api/upload' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "file": {
    "name": "1111"
  }
}'
```

have somebody tried to do like that?